# How disable default Content Security Policy for Rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, content-security-policy

I'm using the gem `secure-headers` to handle CSP in my Rails project, but I'm getting this header by default: `Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' https:; font-src 'self' https: data:; img-src 'self' https: data:; object-src 'none'; script-src https:; style-src 'self' https: 'unsafe-inline'` alongside the CSP-Report-Olny Header, and I'd like to disable it.

I already tried to write something like this in my `config/application.rb`, but it didn't work.

```rb
config.action_dispatch.default_headers['Content-Security-Policy'] = ''
config.action_dispatch.default_headers.delete('Content-Security-Policy')
```

My `config/initializers/secure_headers.rb` file:

```rb
SecureHeaders::Configuration.default do |config|
  config.csp_report_only = {
    default_src: %w['self' fonts.gstatic.com],
    img_src: %w['self'],
    font_src: %w['self' fonts.gstatic.com],
    script_src: %w['self'],
    connect_src: %w['self'],
    report_uri: %w[/my-route]
  }
end
```

Has anyone ever experienced this?

Ruby: 2.6.3

Rails: 5.1.2

I'd like to disable the default CSP header and use only Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only

Comment: Did Rails 5 even ship with CSP middleware built in or do you possibly have another gem setting the headers? You can inspect the stack with `rake middleware` and then remove or replace the middleware.  https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/rails_on_rack.html#internal-middleware-stack

Comment: There was a default setting, it was in the gem's documentation, it was simple, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [gem's documentation](https://github.com/github/secure_headers#default-values), if you don't set any settings or use `SecureHeaders::OPT_OUT` to ignore, it would pick up by default. So the solution was simple.

```rb
config.csp = SecureHeaders::OPT_OUT
```